# sum of integers. add them. check if sum is odd or even. print the sum of digits and also print if odd or even

Tags: java, sum

enter an integer number. Find the sum of the digits of the number and check if the sum of the digits is odd or even. Print the sum of digits and also print Odd or Even.
this is what i have so far (Updated with final result. Thank you all for your help)

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumofDigits {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.print("Enter number so it could be added: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int sum = 0;
    int num = input.nextInt();

    while (num > 0){
        int digit = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        sum += digit;

    }
    if (sum % 2 ==0){
                System.out.println("Even");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Odd");
            }
            System.out.println("The Sum of the digits is: " + sum);
                }
         /*
         //this is what i put, but was wrong. 
           sum = sum + num;
           num = num / 10;


        System.out.println("Sum of digits: " + sum);
        //ends here
         */
```

{
    }

OUTPUT

Enter number so it could be added: 12334

Odd

The Sum of the digits is: 13

Comment: Is this your homework? You'll need to write some code first and then tell us where you need help. The point of SO isn't for people to do the work for you.

Comment: sorry, i am new to this site.

Comment: No worries. Just write the code and try to solve it on your own. If you become stuck then come back with a question that best describes the problem you're having.

Comment: i am new to java. first time taking the course. thanks.

Comment: i managed to identify if the sum is either even or odd. just cant make the code to add the digit that is entered .

Comment: So if the integer entered is `111` the output should be `3` because you'll do `1+1+1` ?

Comment: yes. then after the number prints. another line prints whether the solution is even or odd

Comment: Please don't post your code as an Answer.  Put it into the Question.    Use the "edit" link ....

Comment: got it.  ill erase the code from the Answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this.  All of the changes you are making (posting multiple versions of your code, etc) make this impossible to understand for people who can't read the history.  Therefore, it is not useful for the kind of (future) reader who *might* find it.  Besides, you have gotten the solution to your problem.

Comment: how do i change this so it could help other people?

Comment: Too late.  Just delete the question before it attracts downvotes.  (For what it is worth, I don't think that it would be useful anyway.)  But for future reference.  1) Put your real code into the Question from the start.  2)  Don't edit it to track the changes you make to fix the bugs.  3) Don't put the answer into the Question, and don't put updates to the Question into Answers.  4) THINK about what a future reader might want.  Put yourself into their shoes.

Comment: im really sorry. im new to asking questions on here. this was my first question. but i will delete

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you can start by using **Scanner** to take input of two numbers and then add them.

- Use `java.util.Scanner;`
- Store input into two different int using `scanner.nextInt();`

Comment: i put import java.util.Scanner;

Answer (score 0):

The code you have seems like it would work. I took what you had and made a few updates but its pretty much the same. Maybe you'll see a difference in your real code vs what I have.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    int num = input.nextInt();

    while (num > 0) {
        int digit = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        sum += digit;
    }

    if (sum % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Even");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Odd");
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: that is what i have but when i run it. it does not add the digits.

Comment: I would paste everything you have so we might see something we're not seeing in your current post.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see wrong with the code in your Question (apart from the odd typo) is that you don't print out the sum.

It looks like you are calculating the sum just fine ... but don't expect Java to know that you want it to print if you don't **tell it** to do that.

Comment: i saw what you meant. i fixed it. and ran it and it all works out. i will edit the question with my final code and the output.   THANK YOU.